# Remove OrderItem Meta Data

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

This is how I set custom meta data for a product which gets added to basket:

```
    add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_create_order_line_item', 'save_cart_item_custom_meta_as_order_item_meta', 10, 4 );
function save_cart_item_custom_meta_as_order_item_meta( $item, $cart_item_key, $values, $order ) {
    
    $meta_key1 = 'Product 1';
    
    if ( isset($values['add_size']) && isset($values['add_size'][$meta_key1]) ) {
        $item->update_meta_data( $meta_key1, $values['add_size'][$meta_key1] );
    }
```

I need to remove this custom meta data after a purchase ('woocommerce_thankyou') but first I need to use it to add a product to the order.

```
add_action('woocommerce_thankyou', 'add_order_gift_note', 10, 1);
function add_order_gift_note( $order_id ) {
    foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item_id => $item ) {
$extras = $item->get_formatted_meta_data('_', true);
                foreach($extras as $extra){
                $mini_id = $extra->value;                       
$order->add_product( wc_get_product($mini_id), $product_quantity); // Add Minis 
}
// Now hide or remove the meta data.
```

Either removing it or hiding some meta data from the order at this point is the desired solution.

I don't want the IDs to show in the orders: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jXhmv.jpg

Comment: There might be a better framework built in solution, but you can always fall back on [array_map](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) and apply a callback to modify the items.

Comment: Can you please give an example of how array_map would work in my situation

Comment: Could you display on which of your collections in the PHP code this field is defined?

Comment: What do you mean by collections? I add the item to basket like so: https://imgur.com/a/vKZUf1Y and I make sure it saves with the woocommerce_checkout_create_order_line_item function (first code) - from $meta_key7 onwards, I can't have them displayed in the order